# How to ensure at compile time that messages are send to the right Actor in Akka.net?

Tags: interface, compile-time, type-safety, akka.net

Since Akka.net system returns only a reference (IActorRef) to an Actor and you are only able to interact with the Actor through Tell() and Ask() where the parameters are not strongly typed and are just of type object base... there are some questions raising in my head.

How do you ensure that you are "talking" to the right Actor type at compile time? (e.g. if you are receiving only a IActorRef in a constructor of a class instead of a concrete interface contract or throug request to the Actor System, then you don't know that the Actor is able handle that message)
How do you ensure that the Actor is of a specific type and how to know that you are selecting the right message for this type?

Even though the loose coupling is nice it has more disadvantages than advantages with the "TellAnything" a object contract aproach (from my point of view) and Microsoft Orleans Grains seems to me a better fit here as you can have an explicit interface. Do I miss a functionality that Akka.net provides to have serious contracts?

**Microsoft Orleans with explicit interface:**

```
public interface IHello : Orleans.IGrainWithIntegerKey
{
  Task<string> SayHello(string greeting);
}

public class HelloGrain : Orleans.Grain, IHello
{
  Task<string> SayHello(string greeting)
  {
    return Task.FromResult($"You said: '{greeting}', I say: Hello!");
  }
}

// Get a reference to the IHello grain with id '0'.
var friend = GrainClient.GrainFactory.GetGrain<IHello>(0);

// Send a greeting to the grain and await the response.
Console.WriteLine(await friend.SayHello("Good morning, my friend!"));
```

**Akka.net complains only about Tell and Ask (with object parameters):**

Is there something simular in Akka.net that allows explicit contracts? I know there are Proxies for using Akka in Java that supports that but Akka.net seems to have nothing comparable here.

```
MyActorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem");

// create top-level actors within the actor system
Props consoleWriterProps = Props.Create<ConsoleWriterActor>();
IActorRef consoleWriterActor = MyActorSystem.ActorOf(consoleWriterProps, "consoleWriterActor");

// now you can tell everything to consoleWriterActor at compile time (even though this Actor only understands a specific message)

// begin processing
consoleReaderActor.Tell(ConsoleReaderActor.StartCommand);
```

How to ensure that clients of the "interface only use the right commands?

Would be nice if Akka.net had something like this:

```
Props consoleWriterProps = Props.Create<ConsoleWriterActor>();
IConsoleWriter consoleWriterActor = MyActorSystem.ActorOf<IConsoleWriter>(consoleWriterProps, "consoleWriterActor");

consoleReaderActor.MyExplicitCallThatAllowsOnlyStartCommandType(ConsoleReaderActor.StartCommand);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface contracts through [Akka.Interfaced](https://github.com/SaladLab/Akka.Interfaced), this however introduces next level of complexity and indirection, which can cause performance drop, block some more advanced messaging patterns and dynamic behavior switching in your actors.

Other approach is to wrap `IActorRef` with a typed version of it allowing you to ensure, that only specific types of messages can be passed through Tell method - which is exactly how [Akkling](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling) works.